# What to return from "doc* dequeue(queue *front)" in Queue data structure when my Queue is empty?

Tags: data-structures, queue

```
typedef struct Doc
    {
        int id;
        char name[50];
        struct Doc *next;
    }doc;
    
    typedef struct Queue
    {
         doc *front;
        doc *rear;
    }queue;
    
    doc* dequeue(queue *q)
    {
        if(q->front == NULL)
        {
            printf("Queue is empty!\n");
            system("pause");
            return -1; ///code is not working with -1 return value.
        }

        doc *temp;
        temp = q->front;
        q->front = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;

        return temp;
    }
```

In the code, I am returning a doc* type memory address. Now what to return, when my queue is empty?
I am taking the doc* type output because I want to store the dequeued data in a recycle bin stack and want to use it later. Note that, I am using C language.

Comment: Return `NULL` instead of -1, but also: the caller must check what it gets returned. If it is that `NULL`, then the caller should not try to treat it as if it references a doc.